# Copiar o valor de uma variável tipo list, para uma outra em python

Tags: python, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, append

Estou declarando uma variável **X** com o valor de outra **Y** usando `=`, mas quando tendo fazer um `append` na variável **X**, a **Y** também muda.

Código:

```
'''
Resultado obtido:
['casaRJ', 'casaSP', 'casaDF', 'apRJ', 'apSP']                                                                                
['casaRJ', 'casaSP', 'casaDF', 'apRJ', 'apSP']

Resultado esperado:
['casaRJ', 'casaSP', 'casaDF']                                                                                
['casaRJ', 'casaSP', 'casaDF', 'apRJ', 'apSP']

'''

variavel_casas = ['casaRJ', 'casaSP', 'casaDF']
variavel_outros = ['apRJ', 'apSP', 'apDF']

principal = variavel_casas
suporte = variavel_casas

if 'casaRJ' in str(variavel_casas): suporte.append('apRJ')
if 'casaSP' in str(variavel_casas): suporte.append('apSP')

print(principal)
print(suporte)
```

Como eu poderia resolver isso? E por que isso ocorre? 
Onde está o problema no código, e de que maneiras eu poderia fazer isso corretamente?

Comment: Por que você está convertendo a lista para string, se o teste com `in` funciona também com as listas?

Comment: Desconhecia, ainda estou aprendendo esses detalhes. Obrigado pela dica @GustavoSampaio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em python quando se trata de variáveis do tipo container  (listas, dicionários, etc) a ideia é ligeiramente diferente da de outras linguagens, quando vc faz `var1 = [value1, value2..]`, `var1` funciona como uma espécie de "aliás" para o endereço (na memoria) da lista, então se vc faz: `var2 = var1`, vc está apenas criando um novo "label" para o endereço da lista, veja esse exemplo:

```
casas1 = ['casa1', 'casa2', 'casa3']
casas2 = casas1
casas2[0] = 'casa99'

print(casas1)
['casa99', 'casa2', 'casa3']
```

Veja os `id`s das varáveis:

```
id(casas1)
140096910106120

id(casas2)
140096910106120
```

Para resolver o problema voce precisa utilizar o metódo `copy()`, veja o mesmo exemplo, agora com `copy()`:

```
casas1 = ['casa1', 'casa2', 'casa3']
casas2 = casas1.copy()
casas2[0] = 'casa99'

print(casas1)
['casa1', 'casa2', 'casa3']
```

Veja que agora os `id`s são diferentes:

```
id(casas1)
140096885079112

id(casas2)
140097875390664
```

Se voce quer copiar as variaveis, nas linhas onde vc faz:

```
principal = variavel_casas
suporte = variavel_casas
```

Deveria fazer:

```
principal = variavel_casas.copy()
suporte = variavel_casas.copy()
```

Comment: Só é possível efetuar a cópia do valor da variavel do tipo list ? consigo fazer com tipos primitivos com string e int ?

Comment: @RobsonSilva, Dentro do espaço aqui vou tentar explicar (teste em um shell python): se vc fizer `a="a"` e depois `b=a` vc cria o objeto str `a` e depois faz uma copia desse objeto para  `b`, teria como `True` se fizesse `a==b` ou `id(a)==id(b)`. Se em seguida fizesse `b="b"` estaria criando um novo objeto para `b` e as duas expressões anteriores retornariam `False`.